# ImportScripts : NetworkError

Tags: html, web-worker

Im doing an importScripts in my Worker file ( JS file ) and it throws an error "Network Error" , im not sure why my script loading is being failed , the same url I use in IE browser the files is downloaded but with in worker it fails with above error.

Help Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this problem and I believe it was because I was specifying a javascript file on a different domain.